# get all tags from several posts at the same time

Tags: laravel

I need to create a query that get all tags from an array of posts.in a many-to-many polymorphic relationship between tags and posts

TAG MODEL

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    //
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Post::class, 'taggable');
    }
}
```

POST MODEL

class Post extends Model
{
use HasFactory;

```
protected $guarded = ['id'];

public function tags()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable');
}
```

}

TAG MIGRATION

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

TAGGABLE MIGRATION

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('taggables', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('tag_id')->unsigned();
            $table->morphs('taggable');

            $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }
```

POST MIGRATION

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('description');
            // 1 borrador, 2 revision, 3 publicado, 4 caducado
            $table->enum('status', [Post::BORRADOR, Post::REVISION, Post::PUBLICADO, Post::CADUCADO]);
            // Para diferenciar entre publicaciones del Sistema (Admin = 1) o de usuarios normales (USERS = 2)
            $table->enum('type', [Post::ADMIN, Post::USERS]);
            $table->boolean('atemporal');
            $table->string('slug')->unique();

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('survey_id')->nullable();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null');
            $table->foreign('survey_id')->references('id')->on('surveys');


            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

CATEGORIES MIGRATION

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->string('name');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('slug');

            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

PIVOT TABLE CATEGORY_POST

```
Schema::create('category_post', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id');

            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

RELATIONSHIP POST

```
public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
```

RELATIONSHIP CATEGORY

```
public function posts()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
     }
```

I have tried this but I can't get it to work

```
    $posts = Post::whereHas('categories', function($query) {
                    $query->whereIn('category_id', [$this->categoriaTags]);
                })->get(); 
// Here I get the list of posts from which I want to get their tags, this is OK.


//But then I can't get the right query to get the tags.
    $tags = Tag::whereHasMorph('posts', function($query) use($posts){
                    $query->where('tag_id', $posts);
                })->get();
```

Any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but you are querying the wrong column, and using the wrong builder method. You want:

```php
    $tags = Tag::whereHasMorph('posts', function ($query) use ($posts) {
        $query->whereIn('id', $posts->pluck('id'));
    })->get();
```

Comment: I get error: ErrorException , Illegal offset type .

Comment: @Alberto if `$posts` is in fact an Eloquent Collection, then it should work. You could try `$posts->pluck('id')->toArray()`.

Comment: The updated suggestion still gives me the same error:  Illegal offset type

Comment: It is not an issue with the code provided, the error is coming from somewhere else

Comment: I have edited the question and added the table post, categories and their relationships.

Comment: What is in `$this->categoriaTags`?

Comment: contains the id of the category... What I need to bring is all the tags of all the posts that contain that category.